# wrote code in java for nutch

Tags: java, parsing, nutch

hello:
I'm writing code in java for nutch(open source search engine) to remove the movments from arabic words in the indexer.
I don't know what is the error in it.
Tthis is the code:

```
package com.mycompany.nutch.indexing;
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.apache.nutch.crawl.CrawlDatum;
import org.apache.nutch.crawl.Inlinks;
import org.apache.nutch.indexer.IndexingException;
import org.apache.nutch.indexer.IndexingFilter;
import org.apache.nutch.indexer.NutchDocument;
import org.apache.nutch.parse.getData().parse.getData();


public class InvalidUrlIndexFilter implements IndexingFilter {

  private static final Logger LOGGER = 
    Logger.getLogger(InvalidUrlIndexFilter.class);

  private Configuration conf;

  public void addIndexBackendOptions(Configuration conf) {
    // NOOP
    return;
  }

  public NutchDocument filter(NutchDocument doc, Parse parse, Text url,
      CrawlDatum datum, Inlinks inlinks) throws IndexingException {
    if (url == null) {
      return null;
    }



    char[] parse.getData() = input.trim().toCharArray();
        for(int p=0;p<parse.getData().length;p++)
          if(!(parse.getData()[p]=='َ'||parse.getData()[p]=='ً'||parse.getData()[p]=='ُ'||parse.getData()[p]=='ِ'||parse.getData()[p]=='ٍ'||parse.getData()[p]=='ٌ' ||parse.getData()[p]=='ّ'||parse.getData()[p]=='ْ' ||parse.getData()[p]=='"' ))
            new String.append(parse.getData()[p]);

    return doc;
  }

  public Configuration getConf() {
    return conf;
  }

  public void setConf(Configuration conf) {
    this.conf = conf;
  }
}
```

I think that the error is in using `parse.getdata()` but I don't know what I should use instead of it?

Comment: What problem are you having? Exception? Not getting intended results? what?   btw, this  new String.append(parse.getData()[p]);  means nothing... as you are not assigning the String to anything.

Comment: thanx for your comment
i have 2 errors
how i can assign the new value of the words in the indexer to the indexer??

Comment: To add words you have the method doc.add(name,value) which takes two strings.

Answer (score 1):

The line

```
char[] parse.getData() = input.trim().toCharArray();
```

will give you a compile error because the left hand side is not a variable. Please replace `parse.getData()` by a unique variable name (e.g. `parsedData`) in this line and the following lines.

Second the import of

```
import org.apache.nutch.parse.getData().parse.getData();
```

will also fail. Looks a lot like a text replace issue.

Comment: thanx alot for your reply ,but i dont know what is the type of the variable i will put in the code (e.g. parsedData) and how  i will intialized to it the words in the indexer and then return the value of this variable to the indexer please reply with a full code pleeeaase

Comment: @hala Your question is not as clear that I can provide any code. I really do not understand what you try to accomplish.

Comment: please Howard help me:
i want to write an indexer filter that take the arabic words from the indexer and remove the movements from this words then return them to the indexer
what i should use instead of the parse.getdata() and what i should put in the  doc.add(name,value) please help meeee please